# Widget test for SelectionArea

Tags: flutter

Does anyone know of a way to test the selectability of given text while using the SelectedArea?

I replaced a lower-level SelectableText and wrapped a page's top level SafeArea with SelectedArea, which works great! But - my widget test to confirm the selectability of given text now fails.

```
return SelectionArea(
      child: SafeArea(
        child: Scaffold(
```

Here is the section of the test that worked with SelectableText but is failing now due to not finding the expected copyDialogFinder.

```
final serialValueFinder = find.text('87893876');

final copyDialogFinder = find.text('Copy');
// no copy dialog because it is not selected
expect(copyDialogFinder, findsNothing);

// select the serial number for copying
await tester.longPress(serialValueFinder);
await tester.pumpAndSettle();

expect(copyDialogFinder, findsOneWidget);
```

I tried to find anything online about testing SelectedArea, but did not find anything.